# Java SpringBoot Websocket with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket

What is the lifecycle of the websocket along with authentication in Spring boot? Although some official documentation is there but its not very elaborate.

Comment: Which information are you missing from the official docs? I'm afraid this question is not answerable as it is written now. Can you add more details or point out what exactly you want to know about the lifecycle?

Comment: OK. I want to know when we have a session already to a website the http session then how will this new websocket session will relate to it for example? That is what if I want the one http user whom I want to connect via websocket. Like that.

Comment: If the question is not very clear or answerable I will close it down. I will rephrase it in some new question in better way.